# Record RTSP camera H.264 stream to MP4 with Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, mp4, h.264, rtsp, rtp

I'm developing an app receiving an H.264 video stream from an RTSP camera and displaying and storing it to MP4 without transcoding. For the purpose of my current test, I record for 5 sec only.

My problem is that the MP4 is not playable. The resulting file varies in size from one run of the app to another showing something is very wrong (unexpected since the recording time is fixed).

Here are my pipelines:

```
rtspsrc location = rtsp://192.168.0.61:8554/quality_h264 latency=0 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,stream-format=avc ! queue ! interpipesink name=cam1
interpipesrc allow-renegotiation=true name=src listen-to=cam1 is-live=true ! h264parse ! queue ! decodebin ! autovideoconvert ! d3dvideosink sync=false
interpipesrc allow-renegotiation=true name=src listen-to=cam1 is-live=true ! h264parse ! queue ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

In a next step I will add more cameras and will need to be able to change which camera gets recorded to MP4 on the fly, as well as pause/resume the recording. For this reason, I've opted to use interpipesink/src. It's a set of gstreamer elements that allow communication between two independent pipelines. https://github.com/RidgeRun/gst-interpipe

A thread waits for 10 sec, then sends EOS on the 3rd pipeline (recording). Then, when the bus receives GST_MESSAGE_EOS it sets the pipeline state to NULL. I have checked with a pad probe that the EOS event is indeeed received on the sink pad of the filesink.

I send EOS using this code: gst_element_send_event(m_pipeline, gst_event_new_eos()); m_pipeline is the 3rd pipeline.

Those exact pipelines produce a playable MP4 when run with gst-launch adding -e at the end.

If I replace mp4mux by matroskamux in my app, the mkv is playable and has the expected size. However, there's something wrong with the timestamps as the player shows it starting at time 10 sec insteasd of 0. Do I need to edit the timestamps before passing the buffers to the mux (mp4mux or matroskamux)?

It looks to me as if the MP4 is not fully written, but I can't see what else I can do appart from sending EOS?
I'm opened to suggestions to restructure the app, in case the use of the interpipe elements may cause a problem (although I can't see why at the moment).

I'm using Gstreamer 1.18.2 on Windows 10 (x64).

Comment: you should perhaps start inspecting the timestamps going from rtsp and the ones going out of interaudiosrc. You can use identity (silent=false and connect deep-notify to see output in application) or pad probe on buffers. mkv stores headers differently than mp4. Regarding different sizes - the questiuon is where are the buffers stuck (queue/inter*/mux/filesink ?) - check logs for `queue_dataflow:5`

Comment: For the record, I decided to ditch the intervideo elements having seen https://github.com/RidgeRun/gst-interpipe/issues/50 and create/manage the pipeline myself. The key to get a playable MP4 was to disconnect the branch containing the mp4mux, then push an EOS to it. For the pausing, I just used a pad probe on the sink pad of the mux to drop the buffers whilst paused.

Comment: you can still answer your own question, even if you did not use the intervideo elements